# unix script sort showing the number of items?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script which is grepping the results of a file then it calls `sort -u` to get the unique entries.  Is there a way to have sort also tell me how many of each of those entries there are?  So the output would be something like:

```
user1 - 50
user2 - 23
user3 - 40

etc..
```

Comment: What does your input look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sort input | uniq -c`. `uniq` does what `-u` does in `sort -u`, but also has the additional `-c` option for counting.

Comment: I am guilty of the useless use of cat all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Grep has a -c switch to count the occurrence of each item..

```
grep -c needle haystack
```

will give the number of needles which you can sort as needed..

Answer (score 0):

Given a sorted list, `uniq -c` will show the item, and how many. It will be the first column, so I will often do something like:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -c |sort -nr
```

The -n in the sort will parse numbers correctly, like 9 before 11 (though with the '-r', it will reverse the count, since I usually want the higher count lines first).